# Subfiles not finding `main.tex` reliably

Tags: latexmk, compilation-error, subfiles, latex-workshop

The minimal working example could not be simpler: I have a `main.tex` file like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    \subfile{Subfiles/subfile}
\end{document}
```

and a subfile inside a subdirectory (`Subfiles/subfile`):

```
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

When I compile `main.tex` using the LaTeX-Workshop VSCode extension, everything goes well and I get the result I expect. However, with the subfile it is a bit more complicated: At first, it does work. But then after another compile, it suddenly fails to find `../main.tex`. If I then change `../main.tex` to just `./main.tex` (which does not seem to make sense), it works again for one or a couple compiles and then I have to change `./main.tex` back to `../main.tex` again to make it work. I am not sure what to think of this semi-reliable behaviour. This is the error:

```
Latexmk: Missing input file '../main.tex' (or dependence on it) from following:
  ! LaTeX Error: File `../main.tex' not found.
```

Comment: Did you change directory to Subfiles before compiling subfile.tex?  Alternatively did you use the -cd option to latexmk?

Comment: I guess this is an VSCode issue, it getting confused about the file to compile and doing so from which directory. When you try to compile `Subfiles/subfile.tex` from the directory where `main.tex` is (e.g. by `pdflatex Subfiles/subfile`), then LaTeX will complain that it does not find `../main.tex`, but will work if you change `../main` to `main` in the first line of `Subfiles/subfile.tex`. If you first change into the `Subfiles` folder and then do `pdflatex subfile`, then `../main` will work, but not `main`. As @JohnCollins said: You/your tool has to change to `Subfiles` first ...

Comment: Adding the `-cd` option to the compile config solved the issue. Regardless, it was most likely a VSCode issue as gernot said. (Or at least I would suspect because of the unreliablity)

Comment: Maybe you, Jan, or @JohnCollins might want to write an answer that Jan then can accept, such that other people with the same problem find the solution here? Thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option `-cd` to `latexmk` when compiling `subfile.tex`.  This tells `latexmk` to change directory to the directory containing `subfile.tex` before compiling it.  Then the line `\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}` is interpreted as intended: the file `main.tex` is in the parent directory relative to where `subfile.tex` is.

If you don't use the `-cd` option, and you (or VSCode) don't set the working directory to that of `subfile.tex`, then the compilation will look for `main.tex` in the parent directory of the working directory rather than the correct place.

Comment: How do I set this option? I have googled for a long time, unable to find an awnser.